# Create custom table of contents with \addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I am making custom sections which take the name from an array made using the [`arrayjob`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arrayjob) package. I'd like to make a table of contents for these custom sections, but it doesn't seem like `\addcontentsline` wants to take a variable argument. Here is a MWE of what I have:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{arrayjob,hyperref}

\newcounter{mysection}
\setcounter{mysection}{1}

\newcommand\mysection
{
\newpage
{\Huge \bfseries \themysection: \sectionnames(\themysection)}
\addtocounter{mysection}{1}
}

\begin{document}

\newarray\sectionnames
\readarray{sectionnames}
{
 First section &
 Second section &
 Third section &
 Four section 
}

\mysection
\mysection
\mysection

\end{document}
```

Now, I tried to use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SectionNameHere}` inside my new command to automatically add names from the (and links to them) to the table of contents, like so, in the hopes of making automatic in-document clickable links:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{arrayjob,hyperref}

\newcounter{mysection}
\setcounter{mysection}{1}

\newcommand\mysection
{
\newpage
{\Huge \bfseries \themysection: \sectionnames(\themysection)}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\themysection: \sectionnames(\themysection)}
\addtocounter{mysection}{1}
}

\begin{document}

\newarray\sectionnames
\readarray{sectionnames}
{
 First section &
 Second section &
 Third section &
 Four section 
}

\mysection
\mysection
\mysection

\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error:

> Argument of \one@VEC has an extra }.

I can use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\themysection}` with no problems. When I try adding the array item in, it gives me this error.

Comment: I think  you get into trouble with `\sectionnames` here -- it seems to be unexpandable. Are you open to other `array` like approaches?

Comment: Small note: You're using `chapter` in `\addcontentsline`, which is not defined there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way with a `\seq` style 'array' from `expl3`, using the upcoming LaTeX 3 format.

The seq variable is stored with `\skeletonreadarray`, the values are stored as comma-separated list and later on the relevant array item is fetched with `\seq_item:Nn`, needing the wrapper `\retrievearrayelement`, however.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_skeleton_sectionnames_seq

\cs_new:Npn  \skeletonreadarray#1 {
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_skeleton_sectionnames_seq {#1}
}

\cs_new:Npn \retrievearrayelement#1{%
  \seq_item:Nn \g_skeleton_sectionnames_seq {#1}
}



\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{mysection}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mysection{%
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{mysection}%
  {\Huge \bfseries \themysection: \retrievearrayelement{\themysection}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\themysection:\ \retrievearrayelement{\c@mysection}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\skeletonreadarray
{
 First section,
 Second section,
 Third section,
 Four section,
 Five section
}

\mysection
\mysection
\mysection
\mysection

\mysection

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! I begin to be convinced by `expl3`:) Is there any reason not to use `\retrievearrayelement{\themysection}` instead of `\retrievearrayelement{\c@mysection}`? This way you can drop the `\makeatother` and `\makeatetter` mumbo jumbo.

Comment: @Andrew: As soon as the O.P. changes `\themysection` to something other than the default  `\arabic{mysection}` there will be problems. `\c@mysection` is always a number however (as long as nobody does screw up that internal representation, of course)

Comment: OK, to cater for this you could use `\arabic{mysection}` or `\value{mysection}`...

Comment: @Andrew: of course...

Comment: I was hoping you'd reply to my "unsexy" question, but not like this… :P Looks like I'll have to do some experimenting 'cause this stuff it is crazy

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I leave this question unanswered while I figure out how this is going to work in my document ;)

Comment: @SkeletonBow: It is at least a working version ;-)

Comment: You have no idea what you've put me through